# Trigger strapi ui toast notification (alert) from backend(lifecycle hooks, controllers)

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, strapi

I am writing some custom code in the backend of my strapi app. Lifecycle hook to be specific and i want to trigger notifications and show it to user. Basically i have an afterCreate lifecycle hook that gets triggered when i create a post and after creating a post I am doing some work lets say i am calling another api when i get the response i want to show it to user on the admin ui and want to show the default alert of strapi but with my message. here is the code for reference

```
afterCreate: async ({ result }) => {
    //gets triggered when the post is created
    //I perform an action here
    //if the action succeeds i want to show the default strapi success alert with my message
    //if the action fails i want to show the default strapi error alert with my message
  },
```